# How to get id from $this->Auth->user() in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp

i am trying to get user info of the already logged in user, i am using the following function,

```
$info = $this->Auth->user();   //returns user info as an array
```

and am able to get all the information regarding the user except it's id.
but i am unable to get user id from the above array.

Now my question is how to get 'id' of the above user.

***Note:*** i am using  2.6.7  version of cakephp.

Any help would be really appreciated :)

Comment: yippy! i have found the solution: $this->Auth->loggedIn() , it is working for me :), but am still wondering why $this->Auth->user() not returns id of the current user :(, any comment??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this

```
$id = $this->Auth->user('id');
```

Comment: it is not working for me, instead $this->Auth->loggedIn() works for me, but why $this->Auth->user() not returns id along with the other info of the user? still confused i am :(

Comment: it depends on how you setup your AuthComponent / Authentication. If you chose FormAuthenticate cake will save the user-data to your session when you login. $this->auth->user('id') returns whatever is in your session.

Comment: Please consider adding at least some words explaining to the OP and to further readers of you answer why and how it does reply to the original question.